# PanelGrid won't iterate horizontally.

Tags: visualforce, panelgrid

I have tried moving around the panelgrid, panelgroup and repeat statements but I cannot get the panelgrid to show the records horizontally. Can anyone spot what I am missing?

```
<apex:page controller="controller_TrophyCase" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form id="theForm" style="">

        <div id="header">
            <b>Trophy Case for John Smith</b>
        </div>

        <div id="section">
            <apex:repeat value="{!TrophyList}" var="T">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="5" id="certGrid">
                    <apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!T.Trophy__c}"/><br />
                        <apex:outputlink target="_blank" value="/{!T.Id}">{!T.Name}</apex:outputlink><br />
                        <apex:outputField value="{!T.Your_Trophy__c}" />
                    </apex:panelGroup> 
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Sample of what it is doing right now. These two records should be on the same row as I have columns set to 5.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apex:panelGrid and apex:repeat [don't play well together](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm):

> Note that if an `<apex:repeat>` component is used within an `<apex:panelGrid>` component, all content generated by the `<apex:repeat>` component is placed in a single `<apex:panelGrid>` cell...

Instead, you'll want to use an alternative means of rendering, something like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!TrophyList}" var="T">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 19%">
            <apex:outputField value="{!T.Trophy__c}"/><br />
            <apex:outputlink target="_blank" value="/{!T.Id}">{!T.Name}</apex:outputlink><br />
            <apex:outputField value="{!T.Your_Trophy__c}" />
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

This will result in a CSS-based rendering of the elements.

Alternatively, you could use [SLDS grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/).

Or you could use a nested list:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!TrophyListRows}" var="row">
            <tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!row}" var="T">
                <td width="*">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!T.Trophy__c}"/><br />
                    <apex:outputlink target="_blank" value="/{!T.Id}">{!T.Name}</apex:outputlink><br />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!T.Your_Trophy__c}" />
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox! I went the CSS route. I think it will actually make it easier for me overall with styling instead of the panelgrid approach.